# gcloud deploy releases promote - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have question, I have this command and this working:

gcloud deploy releases promote --release=MY_RELEASE --delivery-pipeline=MY-PIPELINE --region=<MY_REGION> --to-target=MY_ENV

However when execute the command in console ask me:

**Promoting release MY_RELEASE  to target MY_ENV.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  **

[image]

I would like to set in automatically 'Y' in gcloud deploy command any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [--quiet](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--quiet) flag which disables all interactive prompts and uses the default values instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, with --quiet it is working.